# What is the logic behind calculating diagonals on a chessboard?

Tags: logic, chess

Given the position of a Bishop on an 8 * 8 chessboard, the task is to count the total number of squares that can be visited by the Bishop in one move. The position of the Bishop is denoted using row and column number of the chessboard.

Examples:

`Input: Row = 4, Column = 4
Output: 13
Input: Row = 1, Column = 1
Output: 7`

Approach: In the game of chess, a Bishop can only move diagonally and there is no restriction in distance for each move.

So, We can also say that Bishop can move in four ways i.e. diagonally top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right from current position.

We can calculate the numbers of squares visited in each move by:

Total squares visited in Top Left move = `Math.min(r, c) – 1`

Total squares visited in Top Right move = `Math.min(r, 9 – c) – 1`

Total squares visited in Bottom Left move = `8 – Math.max(r, 9 – c)`

Total squares visited in Bottom Right move = `8 – Math.max(r, c)`

where, `r` and `c` are the coordinates of the current position of the Bishop on the chessboard.

Guys I cannot figure out the logic behind the above diagonal calculations. Please help me find out that by what logic the diagonals are calculated above ??? I JUST NEED THE LOGIC. No code required.

( Also If you can help with the basic behind logic of similar kinds of chess problems or matrix it would be fantastic)

[Chessboard image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gcHe.png)

Answer (score 4):

The top-left distance to the edge of the board is indeed `min(r, c) - 1`. Given that the bishop starts on rank `r`, it can move up no more than `r - 1` ranks before landing on the first rank. It may hit the first file before that if `c < r`, in which case it will only be able to move `c - 1` squares. For example if the bishop starts at `r = 5` and `c = 4`, it will be able to move three squares, not four. Thus the top-left formula is `min(r - 1, c - 1)`, which can be refactored to `min(r, c) - 1`.

Similarly, when heading towards the bottom-left corner, the rank increases while the file decreases. The bishop can move at most `8 - r` ranks and at most `c - 1` files, so the bottom-left formula is `min(8 - r, c - 1)`. That can be refactored to `8 – max(r, 9 – c)`, although this expression seems more convoluted.

Comment: Nice Explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To count elements in the left-top and right-bottom sides of the diagonal (in which  Bishop is placed), the following formula is enough:
n-abs(r-c)-1, where n is the size of the board e.g. n=8 in the above case.

So three (instead of four) formulae can give all the cells that Bishop can visit diagonally:
[8-abs(r-c)-1] + [Math.min(r, 9 – c) – 1] + [8 – Math.max(r, 9 – c)]

Answer (score 0):

This is best illustrated by using this https://lichess.org/editor/8/8/8/8/3B4/8/8/8_w_-_-_0_1?color=white

Suppose you put the bishop anywhere on the board. In that case, you will notice that the number of squares to the board's edge moving like a rook to the left and moving like a rook to the right will be two separate numbers. Still, the distance to the edge diagonally will always be the smallest of those two numbers, for example, d4 moving to the left it is 3 squares, going upward it is 4, and since 3<4, the distance to the edge of the board going "Top Left" is 3. That is what the min() function does, it takes the minimum value. The other min() functions for the different directions are just adaptations of this to make it work for other directions, I hope this helped.

Answer (score -3):

simply apply this formula for any directions: **distance = max(abs(x1 - x2), abs(y1 - y2))**